# Valgrind reports an error on snprintf call

Tags: c, valgrind

I have a very simple program and when I run valgrind for stack overrun detection "--tool=exp-sgcheck" it reports "Invalid read of size 1" error on snprintf call. and I can't figure out the reason.

This is the sample program.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main( void)
{
    char path[128];
    char cmd[128];
    char cmd2[128];
    strcpy(cmd,"Command 1");
    strcpy(cmd2,"Command 2");

    snprintf(path, sizeof(path),"%s/%s", cmd , cmd2);
return 0;
}
```

Valgrind report (valgrind -v --tool=exp-sgcheck ./test):

```
 58 --112952-- REDIR: 0x4eb72d0 (libc.so.6:__GI_strrchr) redirected to 0x4c2b0d0 (__GI_strrchr)
 59 ==112952== Invalid read of size 1
 60 ==112952==    at 0x4E77A94: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
 61 ==112952==    by 0x4EA4078: vsnprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
 62 ==112952==    by 0x4E80CB1: snprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
 63 ==112952==    by 0x4005B1: main (test.c:13)
 64 ==112952==  Address 0xffefffc40 expected vs actual:
 65 ==112952==  Expected: stack array "cmd" of size 128 in frame 3 back from here
 66 ==112952==  Actual:   stack array "cmd2" of size 128 in frame 3 back from here
 67 ==112952==  Actual:   is 128 before Expected
 68 ==112952==
 69 --112952-- REDIR: 0x4eaf550 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c299c6 (free)
 70 ==112952==
 71 ==112952== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
 72 ==112952==
 73 ==112952== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
```

I am using gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 with -g flag to compile the program on CentOS 7 (gcc -g test.c -o test).

Also the error goes away when cmd and cmd2 are allocated on the heap instead of stack.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that [SGCheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/sg-manual.html) is *experimental*. That means it could contain bugs.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. What happens if cmd and cmd2 are declared static (`static char cmd[128];`)? What happens you replace `sizeof(path)` by `sizeof(path) / 2`  ? What happens if `path` is declared static, or allocated on the heap ?

Comment: What is the return value of `snprintf()`?  I'd expect  19.  Yet doubt this is the issue, just another fact easy to discern.

Comment: Declaring cmd and cmd2 as static (static char cmd[128]) still results in the error, and the same happens with the path, no matter if the path is created on heap or stack or static valgrind always throws the same error. Only when the cmd and cmd2 are created on heap, then the error goes away.